# Email-To-Case not creating Case when routing address in CC Field

Tags: email2case

In Email to case, if routing address in "To" field while sending mail, case is created successfully. If routing address is in CC Field with some other email address in To field, case is not created

Comment: Do you mean that if the same email address is in to and cc fields, the case is not created?

Comment: Yes if i put the to email address in CC its not working and case is not created

Comment: Yes if i put the "To email address in CC" and In "To Field any other email" Address. its not working and case is not created. 
@RichardN

Comment: Interesting. It should work when the routing address is in any of to, cc or bcc fields. But why would the same email address be in the to and cc fields?

Comment: If i put any other email address in To and "Email-To-Case"Address in CC. Then it should work but not working.

**As per SalesForce** -
The Priority and Case Origin fields auto-populate the case via the routing address settings when the routing address is included in either the To, CC, or BCC fields of an inbound email. \n @RichardN

Comment: Leave the To address blank and enter the routing address only in the cc. If this creates the case then Salesforce is looking at the to field first when determining if the case should be created or not.

Comment: This will not create the case. case is only getting created once the routing address is in To Field. @RichardN

Comment: @RichardN Any update from anybody !!!!

Comment: @nirmalya Ghosh, it could be a bug based on what you describe. As you have read as well, it is supposed to create the case when it is in either to, cc or bcc. Unless you find any other help, I suggest that you open a support case with sfdc in the meanwhile and explain the problem to them.

Comment: @RichardN I have posted the solution below. please have a look.
Thanks you RichardN for your co-operation.

Comment: Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution -
This is depends on the following settings of email server(GMAIL Screenshot)--

Under Settings
[image]

**In my case, for the solution we have to configure lotus notes mail forwarding settings for creating case from TO, CC, BCC.**